# Istio load balancing

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Here's my case.  `Service A` calls `Service B`.  In my k8s cluster, I have 2 replicas of `Service B`.  Let me say they are `Pod X` and `Pod Y`.  The timeout setting of istio is 5 seconds.  Now, `Pod A` of `Service B` has more than 5 seconds latency.  Can istio route the traffic to `Pod B` after 5 seconds timeout?

Comment: Is it HTTP, or some other TCP-based protocol?  Is there a delay accepting the inbound connection, or does it accept the connection and there is a delay producing the response?  (The most likely answer is "no, it's not possible".)

Comment: Please provide more detailed information for this scenario as some protocols can have keep alive methods that will prevent from reaching timeout limit. Which istio version are you using?